# How to install infyOm into laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have follow the guides from http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/master/installation but got an error when i run the cmd command php artisan vendor:publish.

I got an error says "[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found.

Comment: see video for installation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8CpX4MP1sA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `composer.json` file, following should be present in the file:

```
"require": { 
    "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "dev-master",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "infyomlabs/core-templates": "dev-master" 
 }
```

Then run `composer update`. Problem is with your `laravelcollective/html` part in your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @Nitish Kumar, it seems you know about laravel infyom banya generator. I need your help. look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom