# How to add some textfield in form register (laravel generator infyom)?

Tags: php, laravel, generator, laravel-5.3

I read the tutorial here : http://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/5.3/installation

I clone the admin lte generator : https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/adminlte-generator/tree/5.3

I access it in my localhost. The register form like this : https://postimg.org/image/5gswtx4gn/

I want to add some text field and combo box. eg, level, level, username etc

When I access the code, I'm confused
The code is like this :

Controller register is like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

It's load registeruser in vendor. It's like this :

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The register view is like this :

```
<div class="register-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>

    <form method="post" action="{{ url('/register') }}">

        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Full Name">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>

            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>

            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>

            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>

            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="checkbox icheck">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
    </form>

    <a href="{{ url('/login') }}" class="text-center">I already have a membership</a>
</div>
```

I want to ask, how do I add a text field and a combo box on the form to register? I am confused. because the register view called from vendor(Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers)

Comment: if there exist people who can help me find the right solution?

Comment: its simple add your own view here in this form thing to remember is that form action should not be changes after adding one or more fields just got to create method in your controller and add there name as for previous request its working

Comment: if its not clear you can ask again..@samuel toh

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097071/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page-in-laravel-5-2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844022/laravel-use-same-form-for-create-and-edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some custom field to your registration process because your are using official laravel auth you can add your fields in : `/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php`

and then you can validate and save your inputs in : `/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`

you don't need to add anything to registeruser in vendor because every thing you add will change and replaced after every composer install or update.